# Command PhaseScriptExecution flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter

I'm trying to install my app on the physical iphone ... but give me the error below. I'm using android studio and already configured the device in Xcode.

ERROR:

sent 98452086 bytes  received 120 bytes  196904412.00 bytes/sec
    total size is 98439669  speedup is 1.00
    /Users/MACBOOK/Documents/program/flutter/program/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App: errSecInternalComponent
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    Pods-Runner-dmmzyfkwpqeiqnfflqznvdxxafdh
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone R.